# Apache not redirecting https and www

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm setting up a new example and putting it on a virtual host Apache server (Ubuntu 18.04). I'm having some issues with the Apache configuration because I'm not too familiar with them.

`http://example.com`, `http://www.example.com`, `https://www.example.com` all serve the correct website in its document root.
However, `https://example.com` serves the document root from `main-example.org`.

I have also installed an SSL certificate recently and been told to use port 443? It still comes up as "Connection not sure" so I was wondering if this were the case?

Here is the config file in `apache2/sites-available`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName main-example.org
        ServerAlias www.main-example.org

        ServerAdmin it@main-example.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/main-example/build

        ErrorLog /var/www/main-example/error_test.log
        CustomLog /var/www/main-example/access_test.log combined

        <Directory "/var/www/main-example">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        ServerAdmin it@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_test.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_test.log combined
        <Directory "/var/www/example">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =main-example.org [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.main-example.org
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`http://` has a default port `80`
`https://` has a default port `443`

Since `https` uses encryption, if you just put the encryption on `80`, all the clients that cannot talk securely will be unable to access yous site (and you'd have to write `https://www.example.com:80`)

So you have to do something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName main-example.org
    ServerAlias www.main-example.org

    ServerAdmin it@main-example.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/main-example/build

    ErrorLog /var/www/main-example/error_test.log
    CustomLog /var/www/main-example/access_test.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/main-example">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    ServerAdmin it@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_test.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_test.log combined
    <Directory "/var/www/example">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =main-example.org [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.main-example.org
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName main-example.org
    ServerAlias www.main-example.org

    ServerAdmin it@main-example.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/main-example/build

    ErrorLog /var/www/main-example/error_test.log
    CustomLog /var/www/main-example/access_test.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/main-example">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    #SSLCipherSuite HIGH
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/ssl.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/ssl.k
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    ServerAdmin it@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_test.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_test.log combined
    <Directory "/var/www/example">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    #SSLCipherSuite HIGH
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/ssl.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/ssl.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

essentially this means that you are serving he same folder twice. there may be some optimizations to be found.

For more protocols and their standard port numbers see https://opensource.com/article/18/10/common-network-ports or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers